# Web API and OData for change tracking?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm currently using Web APi 2 controllers, DTO's (using AutoMapper) and a separate service layer. My DAL implements UoW and generic repository patterns with EF6. A typical controller looks like this:

```
public class CustomerTypeController : EntityController<DTO.CustomerType>
{
    private readonly ICustomerTypeService customerTypeService;

    public CustomerTypeController(ICustomerTypeService customerTypeService)
    {
        this.customerTypeService = customerTypeService;
    }

    public override IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var item = Mapper.Map<DTO.CustomerType>(customerTypeService.Get(id));
        return Ok<DTO.CustomerType>(item);
    }

    public override IHttpActionResult Create(DTO.CustomerType customerType)
    {
        return Save(customerType);
    }

    public override IHttpActionResult Update(DTO.CustomerType customerType)
    {
        return Save(customerType);
    }

    private IHttpActionResult Save(DTO.CustomerType customerType)
    {
       var customerTypeModel = Mapper.Map<DTO.CustomerType>(customerTypeService.Save(Mapper.Map<Model.CustomerType>(customerType)));
       return Ok<DTO.CustomerType>(customerType);
    }

    public override IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        customerTypeService.Delete(id);
    }
}
```

This is a controller for a simple entity. I have entities that are much more complex with a number of nested navigation levels.

Using the current solution, I cannot leverage EF's change tracking because of the RESTful nature of webapi. So, when I save updates back to the db, EF generates an UPDATE query with all fields. This is obviously not what I want because:

1. Only changed columns should be sent to the DB
2. My entity auditing doesn't catch the changed columns and their values.

So basically I'm currently using EF6 just for the model designer (I use database first) and for reading tables. And this looks like overkill at the moment.

So to solve my change tracking problem, I would need to use packages such as ChangeTracking or TrackableEntities. I would like to avoid these as I don#t want to add additional references on the client-side or incur bigger payloads.

Alternatively, I could use OData's Delta with WebAPI, although I've read that it doesn't play well with JSON. Moreover, I use Jil and ProtoBuf media formatters too.

The last solution is to use OData controllers completely. But I would like to keep the same structure for my controls as shown above. I'm not interested in OData's paging, filter, sorting, etc.

At this stage I might decide to use OData completely if this solves my change tracking problem.

Is this the only way to go or are there alternatives or workarounds?